# Picasso Images not loading in a GridView

Tags: android, picasso

I am having issues with Picasso, I have a custom adapter loading images by the following:

Picasso.with(this.ctx).load(contact.getPhotoURI()).placeholder(R.drawable.contact_no_picture).into(img);

This is loaded into an ImageView which is placed inside a GridView.

The result is the following:

[image]

As you can see the images are half loaded and in some cases, not loaded at all.

Am I missing something?

Comment: It's not clear from the screenshot what your expectations are, it looks that only placeholders are displayed. Does any of your icons load into the gridview at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Picasso with item renderers in a list / grid, I ended up using the `ListeningTarget` interface the lib provides:

Create a custom class that extends `ImageView` and implements `ListeningTarget`.

```
public class PicassoImageView extends ImageView implements ListeningTarget
{...}
```

In the overridden `onBitmapLoaded` method call `this.setImageBitmap(bmp);` where bmp is the parameter Picasso passes as the loaded image's bitmap:

```
@Override
public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bmp, LoadedFrom loadedFrom)
{
    Log.d("Picasso", "Image loaded");
    this.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}
```

Use this class for the `img` instance in your layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" ...>

    [...]
    <com.your.packagename.PicassoImageView
        android:id="@+id/renderer_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" ... />
    [...]
</RelativeLayout>
```

And initialize it like:

```
PicassoImageView img = (PicassoImageView) findViewById(R.id.renderer_icon);
```

Change your call to Picasso to:

```
Picasso.with(this.ctx).load(contact.getPhotoURI())
    .placeholder(R.drawable.contact_no_picture)
    .into((ListeningTarget)img);
```

Of course it's not necessary to have the `ImageView` implement the `ListeningTarget`, but I found it easier than searching for the right view every time a bitmap is loaded by Picasso.

Comment: I was already using an custom imageview, using the standard imageview seems to resolve the issue.

Comment: Yes, it's a weird downside of Picasso. But this way you can still take advantage of your custom class extension.